# Query result is Wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Here below query use in my codeigniter project and gives me only one record, but when i call this query in database and gives me 3 record.[image]

```
$query = "SELECT `teacher_subjects`.*, `subjects`.* FROM `teacher_subjects` JOIN `subjects` ON `subjects`.`id` = `teacher_subjects`.`subject_id` WHERE `teacher_subjects`.`session_id` = 11 AND `teacher_subjects`.`class_section_id` = 5"; 

$query = $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: somewhere you may not be looping through all the records?

Comment: all rows are matching your criteria, So that's why returning 3 rows, if you want to one row means

"SELECT `teacher_subjects`.*, `subjects`.* FROM `teacher_subjects` JOIN `subjects` ON `subjects`.`id` = `teacher_subjects`.`subject_id` WHERE `teacher_subjects`.`session_id` = 11 AND `teacher_subjects`.`class_section_id` = 5" group by `teacher_subjects`.`session_id`,`teacher_subjects`.`class_section_id`;

Comment: Remove $this->db->query($query); line and replace with return $query->result(); and it works fine.. Issue resolve.

Comment: How do you know it's only returning 1 record? Your question is missing information...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$query_statement = "SELECT `teacher_subjects`.*, `subjects`.* FROM `teacher_subjects` JOIN `subjects` ON `subjects`.`id` = `teacher_subjects`.`subject_id` WHERE `teacher_subjects`.`session_id` = 11 AND `teacher_subjects`.`class_section_id` = 5"; 

$query = $this->db->query($query_statement);
return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : false;
```